# how to make model in django using mongodb

Tags: python, django, json, mongodb

I want mongodb database with django. I configure my settings.py file which have following configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',  
    'NAME': 'events',                     
    'USER': '',                      
    'PASSWORD': '',                  
    'HOST': '',                     
    'PORT': '',                      
}
```

}

As I am using mongodb so I have a json file name events.json. my models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

In sqlite it creates table but how it will create documents for mongodb and where should I put my json file so that it can fetch by mongodb and then it can be access in django.because as I run command in command prompt it shows this error:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

it shows error

```
ordering can't span tables on non-relational backends.
```

Comment: Apparently you need to use `django-nonrel` instead of `django`

Comment: This might help - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-non-relational/PS9HMLDgls0 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188165/whats-the-error-in-my-project

Comment: Have you considered using a [Django to MongoDB connector](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/) instead of a different ORM for your app? The original Django ORM works with MongoDB using this connector.